# How to send an object with other variables back to the client using json serialize?

Tags: jquery, json, django, ajax, serialization

How to add dict `a` to `response` and how can I get `two objects` at the `ajax`?

**view**

```
def abc(request):
    cp = Cp.objects.get(id=1)
    cp = serializers.serialize('json', [cp,])
    cp = json.loads(cp)

    a = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}

    return HttpResponse(data)
```

**js**

```
$.ajax({
    //
    success: function(data){
    }    
})
```

Comment: The ajax should not be expected to return multiple objects.  It should be expected to return one object, or an array of objects.  "An array" being a single top level element.  Returning `"{..stuff...},{...stuff...}"` is not valid json without breaking them apart before parsing them

Comment: `return JsonResponse({'cp': cp, 'a': a})`?

Comment: @Taplar: please do not use a top level list, this is a known security vulnerability: https://blog.jeremiahgrossman.com/2006/01/advanced-web-attack-techniques-using.html This is actually one of the reasons that a `JsonResponse` will refuse to serialize a top level list, unless you specify `safe=False`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what exactly is the security concern with returning a json array?

Comment: @Taplar: malware can override the `Array` function, and thus spy on the result that is returned.

Comment: Malware can do lots of stuff.  That doesn't mean you shouldn't use logic.  If you have an api endpoint that performs a search, the logical way to return the multiple results is a json array.

Comment: @Taplar: we are just talking about a JavaScript script that thus can "hack" into responses of another party. So it has not much to do with infecting the machine first.

Comment: What's to stop malware from overriding `Object`?

Comment: @Taplar: because there is a small piculiarity: a list is a valid JavaScript script that can run, an object on the other hand, not. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43717574/67579), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3503102/67579), [here](http://incompleteness.me/blog/2007/03/05/json-is-not-as-safe-as-people-think-it-is/), and [here](https://johnresig.com/blog/re-securing-json/). The discovery resulted in a lot of frameworks taking countermeasures against top level arrays, including Django, but tornado as well: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1009

Comment: The interesting thing is that, after the discovery in 2006 it has been patched. But it turned out to be insufficient, since there were still related leaks in 2008, 2011, and 2012. I think therefore a lot of developers simply do not "trust" the patches, and use a "better be safe than sorry" approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thnx @WillemVanOnsem for help

**views**

```
def abc(request):
    cp = serializers.serialize('json', [cp,])
    cp = json.loads(cp)
    cp = json.dumps(cp)
    other = {'rate': float(rate), 'eair': float(eair), 'overpayment': overpayment, 'total_payment': round(total_payment), 'monthly_payment':round(monthly_payment)}
    return JsonResponse({'cp': cp, 'other': other})
```

**js**

```
  $.ajax({
    //
    success: function(data) {
      var cp_json = JSON.parse(data.cp);
      var other = data.other;
      var credit_payment = cp_json[0].fields;
      $('.rate').html(credit_payment.rate + '%')
    }
  })
```