# Import javascript array from local file into local python file

Tags: javascript, python, python-import

I have a local javascript file with an array like this:

file1.js:

```
export const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Can I import this array as a python list (or any other data type) in a python script on the same machine and in the same project? Ideally it would look something like this:

file2.py:

```
from ..path.to.javascript.file1.js import arr
```

But this doesn't work. Would it be possible if I exported the array as a JSON stringified object?

Comment: Yes, like XML, JSON is an interchangeable format which can be parsed and understood by multiple languages. So converting your array to JSON, and then parsing it in Python would work. But you'd have to either send the JSON from the client to the server or have a static file with JSON to use it in your Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. convert your .js file to a .json and change the array to proper json format like this:

   {"arr": ["a", "b", "c"]}

   The double quotes are necessary for json format. (Also it's best to embed the array in a json object to avoid a [security vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717574/javascript-why-shouldnt-the-server-respond-with-a-json-array) although it is possible to have an array as json top-level.) Then use the built-in `json` module to read the json.
2. Read the .js file as a string, and extract the list using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). which will safely convert the string to a list.

First approach:

```
import json

with open("file1.js") as f:
    li = json.load(f)['arr']   #note that you use load(), not loads() to read from file
```

Second approach:

```
import ast

with open(file1.js') as dataFile:
    data = dataFile.read()
    str = data[data.find('[') : data.rfind(']')+1]
    li = ast.literal_eval(str)
```

Comment: Note that for the first approach it li will be a dictionary with "arr" as its only key, and the list as the value. So to assign the list to li, do: li = json.load(f)['arr']

Comment: @Alex When I was testing with Visual Studio the file loaded directly into an list. However, testing on the command line and in PyCharm I get the same result as you. To avoid these differences and a security vulnerability with top level arrays, it's best to embed the array in a json object. See my update above.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can write the JSON to a file, you can read it in Python like this:

```
import json

with open("file.json") as f:
    json_file = json.loads(f)
```